# Is it advisable to use the same torch Dataset class for training and predicting?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, pytorch-dataloader

I have recently started using PyTorch and I liked it for its object-oriented style. However, I wonder what’s the best and advised workflow when predicting the model. I wanted to use a custom Dataset class I wrote and which I use for training and validating my model. This class is a map-style dataset, therefore I implement `__getitem__` method to return image and target:

```
class CustomDataset:

    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...

    def __getitem__(self, image_id):
        ....
        return (
            torch.tensor(image, dtype=torch.float),
            torch.tensor(target, dtype=torch.long),
       )
```

However, when I’m using this class for predicting I don’t have any targets to return. My current workaround is something like

```
def __getitem__(self, image_id):
    ....
    if predict:
        return (
            torch.tensor(image, dtype=torch.float),
            np.nan,
       )
   else:
        return (
             torch.tensor(image, dtype=torch.float),
             torch.tensor(target, dtype=torch.long),
       )
```

However, I wonder if there’s a better way to do it. And at the same time, as it feels a bit unnatural, I started wondering if it is even advisable to use the same class for training and predicting (it should be, but the clunkiness of my solutions makes me wonder). Of course, I could not return a tuple at all, but only a first element, but this still needs if-else.

Comment: Can you please explain that what predict function in the above is going to do  ?

Comment: `predict` in the code above is a boolean parameter, set to `True` when we are using the dataset for predicting

Comment: Oh okay, so you are using it as in terms of switching between test and train data, right ?

Comment: If by test data you mean the unlabeled part of data (without `y`) - yes, this is exactly what I'm doing here.

Comment: Yes it can be done, in fact in pytorch lightning module there is a setup function with stage variable to switch between test data(unlabeled part) and train data,
check this out: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-pytorch-lightning-datamodules/

Comment: To be clear, it is common to use the same dataloader object for the training and testing subsets of data (all of which is considered the process of "training"). You would not want to use the unmodified dataloader for an online deployment of your code i.e. inference

Answer (score 2):

PyTorch's `DataSet` class is really simple. So, do not overthink it. It's not much more than a wrapper for accessing your data.

You don't have to return a tuple, not even Tensors. You can return whatever data you want. Commonly, it will be in one of those styles:

- For unsupervised data: `Sample` or `(Sample, None)`
- For supervised data: `(Sample, Label)`
- For supervised data with multiple targets, e.g. object detection: `(Sample, [Label1, Label2, ...])` or `(Sample, Label1, Label2, ...)`

It is also [common](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/datasets/) to use the same DataSet class for train / test.

So, in your case, simply return the sample or a tuple `(sample, None)` [as done in torchvision](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/datasets/celeba.py#L185) and adjust your pipeline accordingly. I'd not suggest using `np.nan` as it would fail a simple None check (`np.nan == None`). Also, I'd encourage you to inherit from `torch.data.Dataset`.

If however, your pipeline forces you to use a tuple or has other constraints I'd suggest to rephrase your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answear. I gave it a try and followed the approach from [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/datasets/celeba.py#L185), with assigning None to `target` when dataset is used for prediction. However, with the test loader I'm getting the error: `TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class 'NoneType'>`. I don't understand why it worked for aforementioned example from torchvision, but not for me. Does the fact that `Sample` is formatted as a tensor in my code matter? (I don't think it does)

Answer (score 0):

You must write code to create a Dataset that matches your data and problem scenario; no two Dataset implementations are exactly the same. On the other hand, a DataLoader object is used mostly the same no matter which Dataset object it's associated with. For example:

```
class MyDataSet(T.utils.data.Dataset):
  # implement custom code to load data here

my_ds = MyDataset("my_train_data.txt")
my_ldr = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(my_ds, 10, True)
for (idx, batch) in enumerate(my_ldr):
  . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want a "pure" (=no if) solution, you could define a "don't care" class, and have your losses ignore it in some way (probably done with masking internally, it is technically an "if", but it is vectorized).

For example, see [CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) has `ignore_index` to handle such cases. This makes me believe don't care class index is the by-design way to go.

```
class CDiscountDataset:
    self.ignore_index = self._preprocess_number_of_classes() + 1

    def __getitem__(self, image_id):
        target_tensor = torch.tensor(target, dtype=torch.long)

        if predict:
            return (
                torch.tensor(image, dtype=torch.float),
                torch.ones_like(target_tensor, dtype=torch.long) * self.ignore_index,
            )
        else:
            return (
                torch.tensor(image, dtype=torch.float),
                target_tensor,
           )
```

---

As a side note, I am using [Pytorch-lightning](https://www.pytorchlightning.ai/) which gives nice abstractions to the training pipeline, and it implicitly assumes only tuples of tensors return from the dataloader, which makes me believe returning other types is "less canonical", which strengthens my belief that the above "don't care" way is the way to go.